# How do I access the name of the current namespace?

Tags: clojurescript

It seems that the `*ns*` object is available all the time under Clojure but not under ClojureScript. Is there an alternative way to access the name of the current namespace?

### Motivation

I have a slew of calls like

```
(define-subscription ::something :other-namespace/something)
```

in which the two occurrences of `something` are redundant. I’d like to be able to write this in a more succinct form like `(define-sub 'something)`, but in order to turn that shortened form into the full form I’d need to have a way to refer to the keyword `::something` without using the `::` syntactic sugar. It *would* be possible just to hard-code in the namespace name, but that feels unsatisfying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the metadata associated with a var of the namespace you are interested in:

```
(defn get-current-namespace []
    (-> #'get-current-namespace meta :ns))
```

Or if you don't want to declare this function in the namespace itself, but need it as a utility method, you can create one like:

```
(defn namespace-of-var [a-var]
    (-> a-var meta :ns))
```

which you can call like:

```
cljs.user> (def a "hello!")
cljs.user> (namespace-of-var #'a)
cljs.user
```

Practically, you can call the namespace-of-var function from another function, passing in the function's own name as var parameter:

```
(defn function-in-another-namespace []
    (let [current-namespace (namespace-of-var #'function-in-another-namespace)]
        (prn (str "current namespace: " current-namespace))))
```

Answer (score 0):

With a macro you should be able to do it:

```
(defmacro defsub [n]
    (let [x# (name n)]
        `(define-subscription (keyword ~x#) (keyword "other" ~x#))))

(defsub blah)
```

Comment: I’m a newbie to ClojureScript but I don’t see how this will namespace-qualify the first keyword (the `(keyword ~x#)` part) in the desired way.